# REGEX for Matching A String Exactly

Tags: php, regex, iframe

I'm having a bit of trouble matching a string using REGEX (PHP).

**We have this code:**

```
<p style="text-align: center; ">
    <iframe height="360" src="http://example.com/videoembed/9338/" frameborder="0" width="640"></iframe></p>
```

**We have this REGEX:**

```
/<p.*>.*<iframe.*><\/iframe><\/p>/is
```

However, this is also matching ALL paragraph tags on the string - not just the ones containing the IFRAME tags.  How can we only match the P tags containing IFRAME?

**We also want to match this code using the same REGEX:**

```
<p style="text-align: center;"><iframe allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" height="360" src="http://example.com/videoembed/9718/" width="640"></iframe></p>
```

Notice that there are no line breaks and less whitespace (in the P tag).

How can we achieve this?  I'm a little new to REGEX.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: You should most definitely *not* use regex for this task, but rather an XML parser, such as [XML Parser](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xml.php) or [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php), or an HTML parser such as the [DOM implementation](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php).

Comment: this may not answer your question, but it may solve your problem to stop parsing (x)html with regex. You may want to take a look at this: http://php.net/manual/de/book.simplexml.php and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: Further encouragement to use a HTML parser rather than a regex: **[htmlparsing.com](http://htmlparsing.com/)**

Comment: Thank you for providing your comments.  I will certainly look into HTML parsing within PHP instead of regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Match only whitespace characters in between `<p>` and `<iframe>`:

```
/<p[^>]*>\s*<iframe[^>]*><\/iframe>\s*<\/p>/is
```

I also added exclude for `>` instead of any char (`.`).

Answer (score 0):

```
<p.*?>.*?<iframe.*?><\/iframe><\/p>
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/sH8aR8/30

```
$re = "/<p.*?>.*?<iframe.*?><\\/iframe><\\/p>/is";
$str = "<p style=\"text-align: center; \">\n <iframe height=\"360\" src=\"http://example.com/videoembed/9338/\" frameborder=\"0\" width=\"640\"></iframe></p>\n\n<p style=\"text-align: center;\"><iframe allowfullscreen=\"\" frameborder=\"0\" height=\"360\" src=\"http://example.com/videoembed/9718/\" width=\"640\"></iframe></p>";

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

Just make your `*` greedy operators `non greedy` `*?`

Answer (score 0):

Use [^>]* instead of .* like:

```
/<p[^.]*>[^<]*<iframe[^>]*><\/iframe><\/p>/is
```